# SP2-0584: EXIT variable was non-numeric error

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm using following PLSQL loop to delete a large number of records from my table. However it is giving me an error that loop exit condition is not correct.

```
FOR i IN 1..100
LOOP
  DELETE
  FROM mytable
  WHERE date <= (SYSDATE - 30)
  AND ROWNUM < 5000;
EXIT WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM mytable
  WHERE date <= (SYSDATE - 30)) = 0;
  COMMIT;
END LOOP;
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: The error code means you have used wrong syntax of EXIT statement. The condition in `EXIT WHEN` should be boolean condition.

Comment: @JSapkota Isn't it a boolean condition? The result of the comparision between query result and zero should be a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be a simple boolean.
This should work and be more efficient.
The SQL%ROWCOUNT attribute will be populated with the number of rows deleted. If you didn't delete any then just exit.

```
FOR i IN 1..100
LOOP
  DELETE
  FROM mytable
  WHERE date <= (SYSDATE - 30)
  AND ROWNUM < 5000;

  EXIT WHEN sql%rowcount = 0;

  COMMIT;

END LOOP;
```

If you aren't familiar with the implicit cursor attributes take a look at this in the Oracle docs - https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/sql_cursor.htm

EDIT: Just noticed the title of the post. The exit that the message is referring to is the exit from SQL*Plus and as such I'm not sure you are running this the right way. Please post all the code and tell us how this is being run.